# Using Omit type on classes with a index type signature results in minimum properties not being required

Tags: typescript

I have a class which has some mandatory properties and can then have other properties defined by classes extending this one (or anyway, some extra properties I don't know about).

Now I'm trying to use `Omit` type on it, defined as

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

If we define the class as

```
class Thing {
  constructor(
     public id: number,
     public name: string,
     public description: string
  ) {}
}
```

We can do `Omit<Thing, 'id'>` and get the right type inference as `Pick<Thing, "name" | "description">`

If we add a `[index: string]: any` to the class to support unknown properties and retry `Omit<Thing, 'id'>`, now the inferred type will be `Pick<Thing, string | number>`.

```
class Thing {
  constructor(
     public id: number,
     public name: string,
     public description: string
  ) {}

  [index: string]: any;
}
```

This doesn't really make sense: when I type using the class, all properties are required even when a `[index: string]: any;` is defined, why would it become a **looser** type when omitting one of its properties? I would expect the return type to still be `Pick<Thing, "name" | "description">`.

Does anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Omit` uses `keyof` to get all the keys of a type and then excludes the omit keys from that. So a definition of `Omit` might be:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
```

The problem with this approach (not that there is another one) is that for types with an index signature `keyof T` always just return `string | number`. This is logical and is the only way it could be. What are the possible keys for `Thing` for example? Well they are `id`, `name` and `description` but also any `string` so keyof might return a union of all of these `id | name | description | string | number`. But `string` is the base type of all string literal types. This means that `string` will eat up all the other string literal types resulting in `string`.

Given that `keyof Thing`  is `string` excluding anything from `string` (with `Exclude<keyof T, K>`) will still result in `string`, given the signature you found surprising.

Comment: Actually, you can try `type ThingKey = keyof Thing` (`Thing` with index) and the compiler will tell you that `ThingKey = string | number`, that i find odd.

Comment: @H.B. Yeah. My bad, that is true, the argument still holds, `string` will eat up the other key names. The `string| number` is because an index signature of `string` allows indexing with `number` as well `class Thing {
  [s: string]: any;
}
let d = new Thing();
d[0]`

Comment: I see... I'll search for another solution to my problem then

Answer (score 13):

### UPDATE FOR TYPESCRIPT 4.1+

Since typeScript 4.1 introduced [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types), you can now write a non-ugly version of `Omit` which handles types with index signatures more gracefully:

```
type NewOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = 
  { [P in keyof T as Exclude<P, K>]: T[P] };
```

You can verify that it works as desired:

```
type RemoveId = NewOmit<Thing, "id">;
/* type RemoveId = {
    [x: string]: any;
    name: string;
    description: string;
} */
```

Nice!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwLAChrWAHtkIAXAJwFdhTDyAKXffAB0oCMRFhpEATAFzRklALbsApuQA0TZm07dhYURKFlyKVLLzyOXHnwkRgmlqUTF1FLXICUmaAF9ccgNoojAD2ua0AXSEwZABPAG5cFxxcUhCWCWgAITA+ACUJUUIANwkAST5oAF5oAHlRRFIAHgQtaWgAIn56gD4InAB6ACpoWPiklPTMnPyizDl8Nx9oDS1A6GDw8ehJoRFxKTmFtqdoTvbXHF6EgDkJAHcyiuq6gGloCS9SCWQ+GAAFckJ48libiRDmqMMMs3rxkNAANb-QgAMzg8xgAFEvKBKEZKm9bs05rA3G9-M42kdoINsnkCsVThdylUamg6o0+C02l0enEEqThhSxroJlMZgEgqE2sxlKpfFoRcwjCYzBYrNMbGhtrt9tEcEA)

---

#### PRE-TYPESCRIPT 4.1 ANSWER

You can make an `Omit<>` that handles index signatures, but it's *really* ugly.

As noted, `keyof T` if `T` has a string index signature is `string | number`, and any literal keys (like `'id'`) get eaten up.  It *is* possible to get the literal keys of a type with an index signature, by doing some [crazy type-system hoop jumping](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25987#issuecomment-408339599).  Once you have the literal keys and the index signature keys, you can build up an `Omit`:

```
type _LiteralKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;
type LiteralKeys<T> = _LiteralKeys<T> extends infer K ?
  [K] extends [keyof T] ? K : never : never;

type Lookup<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
type _IndexKey<T> = string extends keyof T ?
  Lookup<T, string> extends Lookup<T, number> ?
  string : (string | number) : number extends keyof T ? number : never;
type IndexKey<T> = _IndexKey<T> extends infer K ?
  [K] extends [keyof T] ? K : never : never;

type WidenStringIndex<T extends keyof any> =
  string extends T ? (string | number) : T;

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T,
  O = Pick<T, Exclude<
    LiteralKeys<T>, K>> & Pick<T, Exclude<IndexKey<T>, WidenStringIndex<K>>>
  > = { [P in keyof O]: O[P] }
```

I said it was ugly.

You can verify that it behaves as you expected:

```
type RemoveId = Omit<Thing, 'id'>;
// type RemoveId = {
//  [x: string]: any;
//  name: string;
//  description: string;
// }
```

If you want to take the above `Omit`, shove it in some library where nobody has to look at it, and use it in your code; that's up to you.  I don't know that it handles all possible edge cases, or even what the "right" behavior is in some instances (e.g., you can have both a `string` and a `number` index where the `number` values are narrower than the `string` values... what do you want to see if you `Omit<T, string>` on such a type? ‍♂️)  So proceed at your own risk.  But I just wanted to note that a solution of sorts *is* possible.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I prefer to avoid the code I cannot myself really understand, I decided to go for a separate interface to reference when I need the dynamic index part. Is less clean than the previous solution, but anyone will understand that ;)
That said, thank you for your time in making this!

Comment: @Paolo'Callo'Caleffi updated answer to show how TypeScript 4.1 lets you write a nicer version of `Omit`