# Check if an interface has a required field

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

Is it possible to check whether an interface has a required field using Typescript's Conditional Types?

```
type AllRequired = { a: string; b: string }
type PartiallyRequired = { a: string; b?: string }
type Optional = { a?: string; b?: string }

// Is it possible to change this, so the below works
type HasRequiredField<T> = T extends {} ? true : false

type A = HasRequiredField<AllRequired> // true
type B = HasRequiredField<PartiallyRequired> // true
type C = HasRequiredField<Optional> // false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [you can detect if properties are optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579094/typescript-conditional-types-filter-out-readonly-properties-pick-only-requir).  It gets a bit [iffy with index signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827898/2887218), but your types don't have them so I'm not going to worry about them.

Here's how you can extract just the keys of the non-optional properties of an object type

```
type RequiredKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
  ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? never : K)
}[keyof T]
```

And then you can just check if it has any of them or not (if `RequiredKeys<T>` is `never` then it does not):

```
type HasRequiredField<T> = RequiredKeys<T> extends never ? false : true
```

And that gives your desired results:

```
type A = HasRequiredField<AllRequired> // true
type B = HasRequiredField<PartiallyRequired> // true
type C = HasRequiredField<Optional> // false
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I don't really get how to use HasRequiredField. I'm trying to perform a check with a property to see if it is required in an interface.  How can I do that with HasRequiredField?  I'd basically like to have it return a boolean by passing in a property and have it check that property against an interface to see if that property is required or optional.

Comment: Maybe you want `type IsRequired<T, K extends keyof T> = {} extends Pick<T, K> ? false : true;` but it's hard to tell from your comment.  Do you have a [mcve] of what you're trying to accomplish? If so, you may want to ask your own question since the comments on a 1.5-yr-old answer is not necessarily the best place to get a new problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Found another, simpler way to do this that works in at least TS 3.8.3.

```
// if Partial<T> extends T none of the fields are required.
type HasRequiredFeilds<T> = Partial<T> extends T ? false : true
```

Example use cases

```
type Info<TInfo> = Partial<TInfo> extends TInfo
   ? { info?: TInfo }
   : { info: TInfo };

type A = { type: 'A' } & Info<{ abc?: string }>
type B = { type: 'B' } & Info<{ abc: string }>

// Valid
let a1: A = { type: 'A' };
// Valid
let a2: A = { type: 'A', info: {} };
// Valid
let a3: A = { type: 'A', info: { abc: 'hello' } };
// Invalid
let a4: A = { type: 'A', info: { abc: 3 } };

// Invalid
let b1: B = { type: 'B' }
// Invalid
let b2: B = { type: 'B', info: {} };
// Valid
let b3: B = { type: 'B', info: { abc: 'Hello' } };
// Invalid
let b4: B = { type: 'B', info: { abc: 5 } };
```