# TypeScript: Use `Omit` on an interface which extends another interface with arbitrary string keys

Tags: typescript, interface

Suppose there is the following interfaces and function:

```
export interface Parent {
  [argument: string]: unknown;
}

interface Child extends Parent {
  something: number;
  name: string;
}

function func(foo: Omit<Child, 'name'>): number {
  return foo.something;
}
```

TypeScript complains that `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.`. I sorta kinda understand why this is, but I'm not sure how to overcome it to achieve what I want (aka for `foo` to be the same type as `Child` but with `name` not required).

Note that I don't have access to change neither `Child` nor `Parent`.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [An answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827898/2887218) shows how to write a version of `Omit` that behaves the way you want here.  Translating that to your example code yields [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8vYdm).